# My sudzc loginHandler returns only NSString. How to get the returned Innertoken?

Tags: authentication, soap, return-value, sudzc

When I use the LoginHandler generated from SUDZC on a Soap-service's wsdl,
I'll see only the following output:

```
Login returned the value: OK
```

However when I enable service.logging I'll get the following output:

```
<soap:Body>
  <LoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <LoginResult>OK</LoginResult>
     <authToken>
        <InnerToken>21017998-02fd-4ac9-b132-98c0cb2fd1bf</InnerToken>
     </authToken>
  </LoginResponse>
```

I need to get the InnerToken-value and keep it for subsequent SOAP-calls (i.e. need to add
it to the service.headers member).
Anybody ideas on how to get the InnerToken from the above result?

I'm using the following LoginHandler code-fragment.

```
- (void) LoginHandler: (id) value {
  // Handle errors
  if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
    return;
  }
  // Handle faults
  if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
    return;
  }
  // Do something with the NSString* result
  NSString* result = (NSString*)value;
  NSLog(@"Login returned the value: %@", result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the (generated) SoapRequest.m file I changed the following:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    ...
    if(self.handler != nil && [self.handler respondsToSelector: self.action]) {
        objc_msgSend(self.handler, self.action, output);
}
```

into:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    ...
    if(self.handler != nil && [self.handler respondsToSelector: self.action]) {
        objc_msgSend(self.handler, self.action, element);
}
```

which solved my issue!